# Unable to connect to MariaDB using Invoke-SQLcmd

Tags: mariadb, powershell

I have tried this a ton of different ways and I can't figure out why the syntax isn't working :

I have mariaDB running on localhost 127.0.0.1:3306 and I'm able to connect successfully in MySQL Workbench, however I'm not able to get anything but errors in PowerShell.

```
Invoke-SQLcmd -Query "SELECT * from database.table;" -ServerInstance "localhost" -Database "database" -Username "username" -Password "Password"
```

However I continue to get the following error:

**Incorrect syntax was encountered while parsing ''.**

I've re-arranged things and tried a different syntax, I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: mysql -h localhost -u root -ppassword -e "SELECT ..."

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is the cmdlet itself. That cmdlet is a SQL Server cmdlet and works for connecting to SQL Server https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps

I do not think it is designed to work for MySQL/MariaDB